# Mutable List not updating when adding list elements from within onSuccessListener

Tags: android, list, kotlin, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to read all the documents from a firestore database collection and pass the results to a mutable list of my "Message" object to be used in my Recycler view adapter but the .add() method is not working and the list is not affected when being modified within the OnSuccessListener would like some help

```
private fun getMessages(){
    messageCollecion.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents->
            for(document in documents){
                val currentUser = document.getString(KEY_USER)
                val currentMessage = document.getString(KEY_MESSAGE)
                val message = Message(currentUser, currentMessage)
                messageList.add(message)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("FireStoreFetchError", "Exception", it)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to fetch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
}
```

Comment: have you checked to see if your listener is actually returning data in `addOnSuccessListener` ? that is, does `documents` actually have data?

Comment: How do you check the list?

Comment: @AlexMamo I checked with Logs and Toasts also adding from anywhere outside the listener worked

Comment: @MehranBehbahani yeah I have checked with a toast message to display a key value and it was working

Comment: So you say that anywhere outside the listener, doesn't work, right?

Comment: I mean to say that it works everywhere but not inside the listener specifically the OnSuccessListener

Comment: Can you please share you `Message` class and also show us how you have initiated `messageList`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I couldnt figure out what to do and since my motive was to have the list updated in **realtime** I switched to a **snapshot listener** that I attach to the collection reference from onStart() and this is what the overriden function looks(below) now but the question still remains why can't A mutable list be edited within a OnSuccessListener but if someone else is having issue like me then this will work

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    messageCollecion.orderBy(KEY_TIME, Query.Direction.ASCENDING).addSnapshotListener(this, EventListener { value, error ->
        if (error != null){
            Log.e("SnapshotListener Error","Exception", error)
            return@EventListener
        }
        else if (value != null){
            messageList.clear()
            for (document in value){
                val currentUser = document.getString(KEY_USER)
                val currentMessage = document.getString(KEY_MESSAGE)
                val message = Message(currentUser, currentMessage)
                messageList.add(message)
                chatBoxView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                chatBoxView.scrollToPosition(chatBoxView.adapter!!.itemCount - 1)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**first**, check if your messageList is truly MutableList

**second**, after each change of messageList you have to notify your adapter about the change by:
messagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

you can peek a better method for notifying your adapter, check here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I don't think the question is why the data is not shown in the recyclerview. the problem is that values are not added to the list.

Comment: It is a mutable list because using the . add method i can add elements from any other part of the file and have tested with offline declared data as well the recycler view is fine and as of this method i am simply populating the list from the database before setting the adapter

Comment: so based on your previous answers(listener is called and list is mutable, connection between list and view is ok) I can assume you've made some typo, wrong list assigning or other simple bug. Without full code its hard to say for sure.